# Run AngularJS service with priority

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I need to run a service as soonas my webapp starts.
I must be sure that this service runs first before everything else because I'll get a server-side token that I will use in every next request.
I'm asking where (in the AngularJS pipeline) call this service and if there is a way to put the webapp in "waiting status" until I get the response from the server... otherwise every next request without a vaild token will fail.

Thank you!

Comment: which router are you using? If it's ui-router can do resolve in top level parent state

Comment: Yes... I'm using ui-router!
Putting it in the top level parent, will it stop the execution of the rest of the code until it's finisehd?

Comment: A `resolve` would fire before any services your controllers try to access. Make sure to return promise from that absolute top level resolve. Also all the rest of states would need to children of that top level